# Тире необходимо?

Tags: пунктуация

Необходимо ли тире в данном предложении: "Завтра - первый день в твоей новой школе"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, здесь наречие  *завтра*  подлежащее, а *первый день*  - сказуемое, выраженное словосочетанием, в котором главное слово является существительным в именительном падеже.

Answer (score 0):

Элен права, тире нужно. Но, по-моему, потому, что это предложение неполное с опущенным сказуемым (будет).

Answer (score 0):

Согласна с Лаpf: это неполное предложение, завтра - обстоятельство. Но тире здесь, мне кажется, можно и не ставить. Всё зависит от интонации.

У реки дом. Завтра праздник. Через неделю Восьмое марта. В этих неполных предложениях тоже есть обстоятельство и опущено сказуемое, но интонационно обстоятельство не выделено, логическое ударение на него не падает, паузы нет, поэтому тире не ставится.

Comment: Согласна! Но я его прочитала именно с такой интонацией.